# Passing data between Stack navigators in one Drawer navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

Is possible to pass data between two stack navigators, in one drawer navigator?
i.e:

-DrawerNavigationA
--StackNavigationA
--StackNavigationB

I want to pass some data (you can see in code below) from StackNavigationB to StackNavigationA. What I need to do? I am looking a 3rd day for some solution, but I found nothing.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigator from './routes/drawer';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Navigator />
  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Hello {/* here i want to show a passed value from ChooseName */} from home! </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});
```

**ChooseName.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default function ChooseName({ navigation }) {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([
    { name: 'Adam', key: '1' },
    { name: 'Ivan', key: '2' },
    { name: 'Josh', key: '3' },
  ]);

  //after clicking on the name
  const onPressHandler = (name) => {
    // //Do something to pass name to Home screen
    // //and navigate to Home screen
    navigation.navigate('HomeStack');
    console.log('hello' + name);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList data={names} renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressHandler(item.name)}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{ item.name }</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    name: {
        padding: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
    }
});
```

**HomeStack.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Home from '../screens/Home';

const screens = {
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Home',
    },
  },
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTintColor: '#444',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#eee', height: 60 }
  }
});

export default HomeStack;
```

**ChooseNameStack.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import ChooseName from '../screens/ChooseName';

const screens = {
    ChooseName: {
        screen: ChooseName,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'ChooseName'
        },
    },
}

const AboutStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTintColor: '#444',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#eee', height: 60 },
  }
});

export default AboutStack;
```

**router.js**

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// stacks
import HomeStack from './HomeStack';
import ChooseNameStack from './ChooseNameStack';

// drawer navigation options
const RootDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    HomeStack: {
        screen: HomeStack,
    },
    ChooseNameStack: {
        screen: ChooseNameStack,
    },
});

export default createAppContainer(RootDrawerNavigator);
```

**navigation versions**

```
"react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.13",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.4.0"
```

As you can see, I want to pass a name from ChooseName to Home, when Touchable is clicked and then navigate to Home page.

Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass it as props like:  `navigation.navigate("Home",{'id':2222})` and you are able to get it in the next route. Hope it helps

you will change this line in ChooseName.js `navigation.navigate('HomeStack');` in your code to `navigation.navigate('HomeStack',{name:name})`;

then in your Home.js change this `export default function Home({ navigation })` to `export default function Home({ navigation, route })` and add a `console.log(route)` and `console.log(navigation)` to understand the situation that is all

Comment: if you are passing them (both stacks through your drawer navigator) it means whenever from your app if you navigate to both of them you are able to navigate.

Comment: so just pass as i said and log the props if will be navigated route

Comment: and change it to `function Home({ navigation, route })` and log both and you will be totally understood the situation

Comment: Can you simply edit my code and paste it to pastebin i.e. please? Little bit I do not understand your idea. Thanks

Comment: route is undefined :/ and when I am navigating from Home trought Drawer Navigation to ChooseName, and back from ChooseName to Home via navigation.navigate('HomeStack', {name:name}) it does not re-render the Home screen, so the logs does not works. The logs works only in case that I set the ChooseName at the first place in drawer instead of Home, but the console.log(route) is still undefined.

Comment: just re-check em @fauzt becuase there is nothing else with navigating , if you pass it as second item of `.navigate()` you are able to catch it from the next route with its params, you can also check the docs because there i nothing else with navigating! https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Comment: I re-checked this, and route is undefined. You can try it yourself. Navigation flow is like this: ChooseName is under ChooseNameStack that is under DrawerNavigationStack -> to Home, that is under HomeStack that is under DrawerNavigationStack... but I am trying to pass parameter throught 2 navigations, and the route could came to HomeStack, but HomeStack initialize a new route to Home.. this is how I understand this.. It still not works :(

Comment: Maybe I can catch it in HomeStack, because it is next route... but I can not catch it in Home, because to home is navigated from HomeStack.. how to pass same route from HomeStack to Home?

Comment: can you provide all you codes from github and share link